# Is there any way to check whether the QRect contains QGraphicspathitem inside its boundary in pyqt5?

Tags: pyqt5

I have an QGraphicspathitem in the scene. If clicked on the scene, I will get the rect of that grid. Now what I need is,to check whether the QRect contains QGraphicspathitem inside its boundary

Comment: Do you want to check if all the QGraphicspathitem is inside a rectangle?

Comment: No,I just want to know selected rectangle contains QGraphicspathitem

Comment: If I clicked on the scene i will get the event.scenepos.From that i can find the rect area of 16*16 around that point.Now I want to know whether that rect contains QGraphicspathitem or not.

Comment: Do you want to know if the whole rectangle, of center P and size 16x16, is inside the QGraphicsPathItem?

Comment: assume I have rect(0,0,16,16).Now i want to know whether there is any QGraphicspathitem is present inside this rect boundary.

Comment: is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if a QPainterPath P is within a rectangle R (without rotation) if the minimum rectangle containing P is contained in R, and for this you must use boundingRect(). To know if a rectangle (R1) is contained in another (R2) it is enough knowing that the union of both rectangle is equal to R2. Considering that the solution is:

```py
import math
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)

        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 400, 400), self)
        self.setScene(self._scene)

        self._rect = QtCore.QRectF(40, 40, 100, 100)

        rect_item = self._scene.addRect(self._rect)
        rect_item.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("green")))

        # create QGraphicsPathItems

        radius, number_of_sides = 40, 5

        for i in range(4):
            pos = QtCore.QPointF(*random.sample(range(0, 200), 2))
            center = QtCore.QPointF(*random.sample(range(0, 200), 2))
            poly = QtGui.QPolygonF()
            for j in range(number_of_sides + 1):
                angle = 2 * math.pi * j / number_of_sides
                poly << (
                    center + radius * QtCore.QPointF(math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle))
                )
            path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
            path.addPolygon(poly)
            path_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem(path)
            path_item.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            path_item.setPos(pos)
            self._scene.addItem(path_item)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, timeout=self.on_timeout, interval=60)
        timer.start()

    def on_timeout(self):
        for item in self._scene.items():
            if isinstance(item, QtWidgets.QGraphicsPathItem):
                color = (
                    QtGui.QColor("blue")
                    if self.verify_if_qgraphicspathitem_inside_qrectf(item, self._rect)
                    else QtGui.QColor("red")
                )
                item.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(color))

    def verify_if_qgraphicspathitem_inside_qrectf(self, item, rect):
        """
        Check if a QGraphicsPathItem(item) is inside a rectangle(rect)
        """
        path = item.mapToScene(item.path())
        return rect == path.boundingRect().united(rect)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = GraphicsView()
    w.show()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have added sample image image for you to get clear of my doubt.I have two grids in that scene .one is empty and other is having pathitem.If I press my mouse on any position of that first grid it should print there is no item.If I press my mouse on any position of that second grid it should print there is path item.

Comment: boundingrect() of my item includes both of these grids

Comment: @Python provide a [mre]

Comment: @Python And if half of a QGraphicsPathItem is inside the rectangle then what should be printed?